# How to input internal CSS to content items with CKeditor

Tags: theming, wysiwyg

Sometimes I don't have time to input css in the stylesheet, so I would like to simply add it directly to the article.

Since content items don't seem to have any  tags when viewing source, the tags get stripped.

How can I get this done, for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

h1   {color:blue}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to add it inline, and it shows up when editing before saving, but not showing up on front end, only in back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Filter HTML go to:

/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html

add the `<style>` tag to the limit allowed html tags

[image]

**If the above does not do it**, depending on which one you are using (filter or full html) You need to go to

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced (for Filter HTML)

/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full (for Full HTML)

Then under Advanced Content Filter, select disabled.

[image]